# sump pit not filling like it used to

Tags: sump-pump

Is it possible that work done to the basement slab can affect ground water flow to the sump pit? We recently had a toilet moved in our basement and since then our sump pit has been bone dry. The house was built in 2013 and we have lived here for two years. The reason I am concerned is that we live at the bottom of a hill and our pit usually has a constant flow (outside of winter time) of water and the pump runs every 4-8 minutes depending on rain and what not. Our neighbors along the base of the hill all have discharge from their outlets. Is this something I should be concerned with or are there other factors at play?

Comment: How's the weather been?

Comment: I feel like we got good snow through the winter although perhaps not as much spring rain as usual. It did run today as we got about 6-7 hours of rain yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t have water coming inside don’t sweat it! But yes a new toilet and rock packed around the line may have provided a new drain path for the water. If the basement is dry I would be happy the work helped the drainage.

Comment: Thus makes sense; the work could have changed flow under the slab or near that corner. The pump did run today as we got a good six or so hours of rain.

Answer (score 0):

Weeping tile is a perforated pipe that captures groundwater from the soil around your foundation and to your sump pump. Maybe the contractor who moved your toilet broke or clogged your weeping tile.

If your pump ran every 4-8 minutes before this work was done and now it does not run at all, I would be concerned.

You can hire a plumber with a snake camera to inspect your weeping tile or you can rent a camera yourself (https://www.homedepot.com/tool-truck-rental/Drain-Camera/CGPF-ECAM-ACE/index.html). Shove this camera into the pipe within your sump pit and see if all is clear inside. It should go all-around your house without major obstruction.

Comment: I got to see the hole and what they were working on and I don't think they were anywhere near the weeping tile. Good idea about snaking it though. It'd be good to see what shape it is in given the amount of water it typically drains.